# AngularJs: format current date inside the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, datetime

**THE SITUATION:**

Inside the controller i need to get the current date in order to compare it with other data.

The code is pretty simple:

```
var today = new Date();
```

In this way i get the current date in this exact format:

```
2015-12-24T12:03:58.170Z
```

I need to format it in order to keep only year-month-day (yyyy-MM-dd)

I know how to format the date in the view but i don't know how to do it inside the controller.

**THE QUESTION:**

How can i format the current date inside the controller?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to instantiate the `date` filter in your controller:

```
function YourController($scope, $filter) {
  var today = new Date();
  var formattedDate = $filter('date')(today, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
}
```